# Is there a hook for when anonymous classes are assigned to a constant?

Tags: ruby, class, hook, metaprogramming, constants

I've been practicing some Ruby meta-programming recently, and was wondering about [assigning anonymous classes to constants](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-creating-anonymous-classes.html).

In Ruby, it is possible to create an anonymous class as follows:

```
anonymous_class = Class.new  # => #<Class:0x007f9c5afb21d0>
```

New instances of this class can be created:

```
an_instance = anonymous_class.new # => #<#<Class:0x007f9c5afb21d0>:0x007f9c5afb0330>
```

Now, when the anonymous class is assigned to a constant, the class now has a proper name:

```
Foo = anonymous_class # => Foo
```

And the previously created instance is now also an instance of that class:

```
an_instance # => #<Foo:0x007f9c5afb0330>
```

**My question**: Is there a hook method for the moment when an anonymous class is assigned to a constant?

There are many [hooks methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127819/is-this-a-comprehensive-list-of-ruby-hook-methods) in Ruby, but I couldn't find this one.

Comment: AFAIK there's still no hook for variable assignments, constant or otherwise ([see here for same question a long time ago](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/65720)). Globals, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a look at how constant assignment works internally. The code that follows is extracted from a source tarball of ruby-1.9.3-p0. First we look at the definition of the VM instruction `setconstant` (which is used to assign constants):

```
# /insns.def, line 239
DEFINE_INSN
setconstant
(ID id)
(VALUE val, VALUE cbase)
()
{
  vm_check_if_namespace(cbase);
  rb_const_set(cbase, id, val);
  INC_VM_STATE_VERSION();
}
```

No chance to place a hook in `vm_check_if_namespace` or `INC_VM_STATE_VERSION` here. So we look at `rb_const_set` (*variable.c:1886*), the function that is called everytime a constant is assigned:

```
# /variable.c, line 1886
void
rb_const_set(VALUE klass, ID id, VALUE val)
{
    rb_const_entry_t *ce;
    VALUE visibility = CONST_PUBLIC;

    # ...

    check_before_mod_set(klass, id, val, "constant");
    if (!RCLASS_CONST_TBL(klass)) {
      RCLASS_CONST_TBL(klass) = st_init_numtable();
    }
    else {
      # [snip], won't be called on first assignment
    }

    rb_vm_change_state();

    ce = ALLOC(rb_const_entry_t);
    ce->flag = (rb_const_flag_t)visibility;
    ce->value = val;

    st_insert(RCLASS_CONST_TBL(klass), (st_data_t)id, (st_data_t)ce);
}
```

I removed all the code that was not even called the first time a constant was assigned inside a module. I then looked into all the functions called by this one and didn't find a single point where we could place a hook from Ruby code. This means the hard truth is, unless I missed something, that there is **no** way to hook a constant assignment (at least in MRI).

**Update**

To clarify: The anonymous class does *not* magically get a new name as soon as it is assigned (as noted correctly in Andrew's answer). Rather, the constant name along with the object ID of the class is stored in Ruby's internal constant lookup table. If, after that, the name of the class is requested, it can now be resolved to a proper name (and not just `Class:0xXXXXXXXX...`).

So the best you can do to react to this assignment is to check the `name` of the class in a loop of a background worker thread until it is non-`nil` (which is a huge waste of resources, IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for the very extensive answer. To make it complete, how did you find this reference to `setconstant`? The documentation in the source (`insns.def`) isn't very clear to me: "set constant variable id. if klass is Qfalse, constant is able to access in this scope. if klass is Qnil, set top level constant. otherwise, set constant under klass class or module." Is this code indeed used to assign constants to (anonymous) class instances?

Comment: @rdvdijk: I guessed and verified it with `printf`.

Comment: I've looked into the source code that you reference here, and understand the meaning of the code you have pasted. However, it does not fully answer my question. This code shows the handling of the assignment of constants, and that this code has no hook available. However, this does not explain when and where the anonymous class finds out about its new name. Following Andrew Grimm's answer, it seems that the method `classname` and related code looks up the constant in either `RCLASS_CONST_TBL` or `rb_class_tbl`, right?

Comment: Your question was whether there is a hook method provided by Ruby for constant assignment and the answer is no. I even searched the Ruby source code to check whether you could work around this by some nasty hack and the answer is no. You did *not* ask how the class gets its new name. Andrew Grimm's answer and my comment to it even answer that question. The key function is `find_class_path`. This means the anonymous class can find out about its new name anytime after the assignment by calling `inspect` on itself.

Comment: No need to be offended! Your answer is excellent, and naturally I will accept it. It is far more extensive than I had expected to get.

Comment: @rdvdijk: I consider it very impolite to take back accepts. This feels like being *forced* to update an already given answer. Not that I wouldn't have helped you if you had just asked.

Comment: I had not accepted your answer yet (and therefore have not taken it back), I asked for more information in a comment. This was wrong, I should've altered my question to ask for this extra information, or open a new question altogether. Apparently my tone was too harsh in the comment I posted? This is quite the experience, it's the first question I ever asked on SO, even though I've answered plenty!

Comment: @rdvdijk: You're right, I made a mistake there, sorry. Of course you were right to ask in a comment, it's absolutely okay :) This is actually what I would have done (and have done before). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes don't actually get their name when they're assigned to a constant. They actually get it when they're next asked what their name is.

I'll try to find a reference for this. **Edit:** Can't find one, sorry.

Comment: The key is the function `rb_class_name` defined in `variable.c:305` (ruby-1.9.3-p0) and the functions called by it (especially `find_class_path`, which uses the `RCLASS_CONST_TBL` maps to check whether the class is bound to a name, at least if my interpretation of it is correct).